# Making an expand/shrink box, with the input tag

Tags: jquery, html

My title might be a bit confusing, I didn't really know how to say it. What I am basically trying to achieve (for the website vhawley.com) is all in this image, which I know, is poorly drawn.

It was just brought to my attention that I can't upload images, per lack of reputation, so here is a link to it. [www.vhawley.com/moc-up](http://www.vhawley.com/moc-up.png)

If you go to the site, [vhawley.com](http://www.vhawley.com), you will see the little default buttons there, and when you click them, they open up more information about each 'topic'. What I want to do is get rid of the buttons, and instead have divs similar to what you see in the picture. Here is my code for the page as it is now.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<div id="site">
<title>Victoria Hawley</title>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1378px)" href="grid-1378.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1218px) and (max-width: 1377px)" href="grid-1218.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 978px) and (max-width: 1217px)" href="grid-978.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 748px) and (max-width: 977px)" href="grid-748.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 747px)" href="grid-400.css">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


</head>
<div id="openImage">
</div>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
var e=document.getElementById(a);
if(!e)return true;
if(e.style.display=="none"){
e.style.display="block"
}
else{
e.style.display="none"
}
return true;
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('VictoriaHawley')" value="Victoria Hawley"><br>
<div id="VictoriaHawley" style="display:none">
This is all about Victoria!
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('Theatre')" value="Theatre"><br>
<div id="Theatre" style="display:none">
This is all about theatre!
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('Gallery')" value="Gallery"><br>
<div id="Gallery" style="display:none">
This is her gallery!
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('Upcoming')" value="Upcoming"><br>
<div id="Upcoming" style="display:none">
This is all about her upcoming shows!
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('Contact')" value="Contact"><br>
<div id="Contact" style="display:none">
This is all about how to contact her!
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Where it says "input type="button", I know I can't just put div, but what is the workaround?

Thanks for any help, and sorry to be a bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace directly by a div, just use the onclick method you defined

```
<div style="border:1px solid black" onclick="return toggleMe('VictoriaHawley')">
Victoria Hawley
</div>
<div id="VictoriaHawley" style="display:none">
This is all about Victoria!
</div>
```

You can see a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/24aMD/1/

Comment: Holy cow, thanks so much. That was annoying the CRAP out of me! Thanks!